# Can't delete database item after page first loads

Tags: android, database

I have a task reminder that allows you to store info in a database and then edit or retrieve them later (like a notepad).  Whenever starting the app and then going to the activity it will display the saved items but will crash if you try to select and delete one.
You can even click on it to review it, just not delete.  If you first add another item then you can delete any and all of them. If I switch to another app and come back to it, it's fine. Only if the app completely shuts down before coming back to delete does it cause a problem.

I'm utterly stumped.

Here is the beginning that displays the items

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    setContentView(R.layout.meds);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

private void fillData() {
    Cursor remindersCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
    startManagingCursor(remindersCursor);
    String[] from = new String[] { RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter reminders = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.reminder_row, remindersCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(reminders);
}
```

And the Context Menu for deleting

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.list_menu_item_longpress, menu);


}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_delete) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        long mRowId = info.id;
cancelReminder();
mDbHelper.deleteReminder(info.id);
        fillData();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

I don't think it's in the database because it will delete just fine if the app has already stored something else.

**EDIT**
I have been trying to debug this problem and found the location of the error in the method cancelReminder

```
public void cancelReminder() {

    alarmid = Integer.parseInt(malarmid);
    Log.e(TAG2, "meds screen alarmid " + alarmid);

    Intent i = new Intent(ReminderManager.mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ReminderManager.mContext,
            alarmid, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    ReminderManager.mAlarmManager.cancel(pi);

}
```

The error is in the Intent for some reason.  This is where I am deleting the alarm for the reminder. It is orginally set in another activity and here is where I am removing it.  What really gets confusing is if the app has been running and I save another reminder I can delete them. If I start the app and go right to a reminder to delete it, it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to the problem....

Trying to cancel the repeating alarm from this activity wouldn't work because it couldn't get the context. Instead I passed the string info for the alarm to my alarmManager class and removed it there.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menu_delete:

        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        long mRowId = info.id;

        Cursor reminder = mDbHelper.fetchReminder(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(reminder);

        malarmid = reminder.getString(reminder
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_RANDOM));
        Log.e(TAG2, "meds screen malarmid " + malarmid);

        mDbHelper.deleteReminder(info.id);
        fillData();

        new ReminderManager(this).cancelReminder(info.id, malarmid);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

and the reminderManager class

```
public void cancelReminder(long mRowId, String malarmid) {


    int alarmid = Integer.parseInt(malarmid);
    Log.e(TAG2, "Reminder Manager Cancel Reminder convert from malarm to alarmid " + alarmid);
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
            alarmid, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    ReminderManager.mAlarmManager.cancel(pi);

}
```